# help me with permissions of next linux files and directories

Tags: imap, courier, owner

while checkin my server, decided to find all files/directories that are owned by user bin.

i found next:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/courier-imap
/etc/pam.d/imap
/etc/pam.d/pop3
/etc/courier-imap/shared
/etc/courier-imap/imapd.saved_by_plesk
/etc/courier-imap/shared.tmp
/etc/courier-imap/pop3d.cnf
/etc/courier-imap/imapd.dist
/etc/courier-imap/pop3d-ssl.dist
/etc/courier-imap/imapd.cnf
/etc/courier-imap/imapd.dist.rpmsave
/etc/courier-imap/imapd-ssl.dist
/etc/courier-imap/pop3d.saved_by_plesk
/etc/courier-imap/pop3d.dist
/etc/courier-imap/quotawarnmsg.example
/etc/profile.d/courier-imap.csh
/etc/profile.d/courier-imap.sh
```

so, is it ok that all of them are owned by user bin?! who have to be owner of those files?

could it be that mail server is compromised?

tnx in adv!

Comment: I gotta ask, what prompted you to look for files owned by `bin`, and what happened to your box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked only a few, but yeah, owned by root. Matter of fact, output of:  `find /etc -user bin` returned nothing.